# modifying settings.xml in $out/maven/conf when downlaoding nixpkgs.maven

Tags: maven, functional-programming, overlay, nix, nixos

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/development/tools/build-managers/apache-maven
Above is the apache maven derivation. When I download maven from nix store it creates a settings.xml file in $out/maven/conf directory which I want to overwrite.
The requirement is to add a step to the above derivation that will overwrite the settings.xml file.
Can this be done by overlays or by overriding this derivation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven package in its [current](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/6cb9067a7238ae413058f522ed505e85da3e8fd4/pkgs/development/tools/build-managers/apache-maven) state doesn't follow the normal `stdenv` phases, but its custom builder does call `unpackPhase`. This means that you can set [variables](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-unpack-phase) to influence its behavior.

```
maven.overrideAttrs (o: { postUnpack = ''
  rm $name/conf/settings.xml  # just an example; do your thing here
''; })
```

Technically it's modifying the files before copying to $out, but I don't suppose that will be a problem. If it is, you'd have to split the `build.sh` script into the usual `stdenv` phases. Then you could use `postInstall`.

To use it in an overlay:

```
final: prev: {  # aka self: super:
  maven = prev.maven.overrideAttrs (o: /* ... */)
}
```